# How to set bold label with ObjectSetText in MQL

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

Is there a way to set **bold** text using `ObjectSetText()` function in `MQL4`.

Should a font name be for example *"Arial Bold"* or can I set a path to the font **`.ttf`**-file?

If a path option is possible, is that path relative or absolute?

Comment: Just a note: On Windows most bold fonts are called _Black_. For example bold _Arial_ font is called _Arrial Black_. However if you are using Wine (linux/osx), there is no such fonts and they have to be installed manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ObjectSetText()` uses O/S-registered fonts & only limited controls

as one may test on GUI panels, `MQL4` operations do not have full type-setting font-manipulation controls available via code

**<sub>( this is all about trading, isn't it? )</sub>**

### Check what fonts are available from your O/S:

[image: Font-selector]

<sub>( or from used Docker/WINE thin-wrapper container )</sub>

So in `MQL4` code there will thus simply be a **`string`**-typed or **`#define`**-ed literal specification of the font name and one may additionally set `aFontSIZE` + `aFontCOLOUR` attribute(s)

```
#define           clrSignalLABEL       clrAqua                  // LITERAL-way
#define           iLabelFontSIZE       24

string            signalTextFONT       'Times New Roman';       // STRING-way
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input bool Font_Bold = true;

string FB;

int init()
{
  if(Font_Bold == true)
  {
    FB = "Arial Bold";
  }
  else
  {
    FB = "Arial";
  }      
}  


ObjectSetText("name", Text, FontSize, FB, FontColor);
```

Comment: Please add a little more description and explanation instead of pure code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.